# Trouble getting string to print random line from text file

Tags: c++

I picked up this bit of code a while back as a way to select a random line from a text file and output the result.  Unfortunately, it only seems to output the first letter of the line that it selects and I can't figure out why its doing so or how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 1000

string firstName()
{
    string firstName;
    char str[MAX_STRING_SIZE], pick[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    int readCount = 0;

    fp = fopen("firstnames.txt", "r");
    if (fp)
    {
        if (fgets(pick, MAX_STRING_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
        {
            readCount = 1;
            while (fgets (str, MAX_STRING_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
            {
                if ((rand() % ++readCount) == 0)
                {
                    strcpy(pick, str);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    firstName = *pick;
    return firstName;
}

int main() 
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int n = 1;
    while (n < 10)
    {
        string fn = firstName();
        cout << fn << endl;
        ++n;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Why are you using C functionality to read from the file? C++ strings are way better to do this. Dynamic size being one of the most important features.

Comment: This being said, in `firstName = *pick` you copy the first character of the C-string `pick`, which is written as `*pick` or `pick[0]` (they are equivalent) into the std::string, instead of the whole C-string. Just remove the `*`

Comment: To your question...I don't know, I'm just trying different solutions I'm finding out there and to this point this one works the best.  I'd appreciate a suggestion as to how to accomplish this using C++ strings.  That being said, thanks for the suggestion of removing the "*", it worked perfectly.

Comment: @JeremySharp You now know that if you remove the "*" in this particular program, it magically works. So basically, you have learned nothing. Do yourself a favor and read up on the details of C++ strings (including the constructor reference provided by Karthik T in his answer).

Comment: @us2012 Yeah, I was aware of that...thanks.  I have been reading up on C++ strings but don't quite know how they work yet...thus, I requested a suggestion.  Constructors is one I will look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 firstName = *pick;
```

I am guessing this is the problem.

`pick` here is *essentially* a pointer to the first element of the array, `char*`, so of course `*pick` is of type `char`.. or the first character of the array.

Another way to see it is that `*pick == *(pick +0) == pick[0]`

There are several ways to fix it. Simplest is to just do the below.

```
return pick;
```

[The constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) will automatically make the conversion for you.

Comment: Nitpick: `pick` isn't a `char*`, it is an array type.

Comment: That worked, as did the suggestion above, but it seems that neither is getting me to where I really need to be.  Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: @JeremySharp where is it that you "need to be"?

Comment: @KarthikT I'm looking for the most efficient way to randomly select something (name, hometown, etc.) from a text file.  I'm looking for efficient because I expect to repeat that selection many many times.I've tried a variety of methods and most of them, like the one I posted here, work (now) but I don't quite know why.  That's it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JeremySharp Efficiently reading from a file multiple times is called loading it into memory :)

Comment: @KarthikT Thanks.  That's what I figured but am still trying to learn how.  Looks like I have some good suggestions here on how, just have to learn how to make them work!

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify the format of your file, I'll cover both cases:  fixed record length and variable record length; assuming each text line is a record.

### Reading Random Names, Fixed Length Records

This one is straight forward.

1. Determine the index (random) of the record you want.
2. Calculate the file position = record length * index.
3. Set file to the position.
4. Read text from file, using `std::getline`.

### Reading Random Names, Variable Length Records

This assumes that the length of the text lines vary.  Since they vary, you can't use math to determine the file position.

To randomly pick a line from a file you will either have to put each line into a container, or put the file offset of the beginning of the line into a container.

After you have your container establish, determine the random name number and use that as an index into the container.  If you stored the file offsets, position the file to the offset and read the line.  Otherwise, pull the text from the container.

Which container should be used?  It depends.  Storing the text is faster but takes up memory (you are essentially storing the file into memory).  Storing the file positions takes up less room but you will end up reading each line twice (once to find the position, second to fetch the data).

Augmentations to these algorithms is to memory-map the file, which is an exercise for the reader.

### Edit 1: Example

```
include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::fstream;

// Create a container for the file positions.
std::vector< std::streampos > file_positions;

// Create a container for the text lines
std::vector< std::string > text_lines;

// Load both containers.
// The number of lines is the size of either vector.
void
Load_Containers(std::ifstream& inp)
{
  std::string    text_line;
  std::streampos file_pos;
  file_pos = inp.tellg();
  while (!std::getline(inp, text_line)
  {
    file_positions.push_back(file_pos);
    file_pos = inp.tellg();
    text_lines.push_back(text_line);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input.  I'm reading variable length records, so I think you're second answer applies.  I've tried storing the records in a vector but (1) I can't figure out how to randomly add records to the vector, I can only do it manually, and (2) when I do add the records manually, ie. push_back a large number of records, it throws me an error.  So, I'm trying to learn how to get to what you're suggesting, but keep getting stuck.

Comment: @JeremySharp:  See my **Edit 1**, as I gave an example of reading.  Accessing the items requires treating the vector as an array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have to work with it...I'm not sure I'm getting it offhand, but the concept seems to make sense.

Comment: @JeremySharp:  Remember to click on the check mark of this answer if you like it.